# Reduce number of colors in illustrator using Recolor artwork not working?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, color-conversion

Here is my problem:

1. I select all my items
2. click the recolor wheel
3. merge some colors
4. click ok, but it does not seem to change:
5. deselect, then reselect the shapes
6. click the color wheel: all colors are back, my color merges are deleted!!

See it in action:

[image: Recolor artwork not working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **change the colorization method to 'Exact'**:

[image]

You can change the colorization method for all colors in the Color Reduction Options dialog by clicking the button next to the presets. Also make sure you have 'Recolor Artwork' checked.

[image]

Comment: This is not enough, I tried it but it didn't work. To make it work I had to click on the button next to `Preset: Custom` and choose "Colorize method: Exact"; then I had to check "Recolor Art", then press ok and it finally worked. I lost a lot of time and hairs because for some reason illustrator does not change the colors if all those requirements aren't satisfied.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I was wrong, but both ways should work (my original answer does and always has for me) but I updated my answer anyway :)

Comment: @arthur.sw  whoever designed the dialog had no idea of how to do ux. The dialog is just completely idiotic, and not idiot proof.